# Random Pick a Month From Last 3 Months PHP

Tags: php

I want to random pick a month from this month and last 3 months. Now is February'16, so the last 3 months January'16, December'15 and November'15.

Below is the php I used:

```
$month = mt_rand(date("m",strtotime("-3 Months")),date('m'));
```

However I got this error:

> mt_rand(): max(2) is smaller than min(11)

because 2nd param is smaller than the 1st param. How to fix this?

Comment: its just minus 0 to 3

Comment: why is the date function inside the `mt_rand`, it should be the other way around, just random the number `1-3` inside the `date` function. just concatenate it like any normal string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the unix timestamps then use the `date` to format the timestamp.

```
echo date("m", mt_rand(strtotime("-3 Months"), time()));
```

Format the date as you choose, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: the number of values between `strtotime("-3 Months")` and `time()` is quite large, i wounder if that effects performance (just thinking out loud)

Comment: @Dagon good point, local testing here has it around .000x seconds, guess it depends on its usage.

Answer (score 0):

am i to verbose with this:

```
$new_date  =date('F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-rand(0,3)  , date("d"), date("Y")));

echo $new_date;
```

Comment: sidenote: in testing this, I got a blank screen on one pass (bizarre). Thought you'd like to know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- odd i tested it a dozen or so times

Comment: it's a "random" bizarreness I guess